# one listening socket and N processes to accept connections

Tags: c, sockets, fork, httpserver

I am trying to make http server which handle only GET in C language where one listening socket in the main process, and then create n workers/processes to accept and handle requests and signals.
I built the listening socket and I am wondering should I create the workers and make outer function to accept and handle or I can create it in more efficient way ?

The main process creates the listening socket but does not accept connections, while the worker process(es) accepts the connections and handles the requests. Each worker process should handle m connections (where m is given in configuration file) the worker process should accept the connection read the request return the response without creating extra threads or forking new process, and serving the requests from one connection should not block other connections.

Comment: Have you heard of non-blocking I/O? `select()`? `poll()`? `epoll()`? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Think about what you are trying to do by having the workers `accept` the connections.  You are forcing all the `fork`ed processes to read the same `fd`(socket) on an incoming connection from which `accept` will then give you a new `fd`.  But which worker is going to handle that incoming request?  You have to have the "parent" `accept` the incoming request then dish off the new `fd`(socket) to one of the workers.

Comment: workers should accept and handle m connections (say 3), and the main process should listen then create workers